# Firefox opens new browser instance instead of using active one

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, multiple-instances

Out of a sudden (it feels like it started with version 67.0), whenever I click a link in a program, Firefox opens a new instance of Firefox instead of just loading the link in a new tab of the already opened Firefox instance.

I'm not aware of having changed any Windows or Firefox settings, and I couldn't find any that may affect this behavior... I'm running FF with a user-defined profile folder (--profile "c:\mydir"), while new instances are opened with the 'default profile' which is annoying.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading Firefox with `--profile` and similar options, then that won't be considered as the default browser as far as other apps are concerned. It's similar to running Firefox with `--no-remote`.

If you want to use `mydir` as your default profile and have it used for everything, you should add it set it as your default in `profiles.ini` (or via `-profilemanager`) and then load Firefox normally without any additional parameters. As a sanity check, this should mean that if all browsers are closed and you open a URL, Firefox should load with the profile `mydir` and load the requested URL in a new tab.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much! In case anyone doesn't know where to find profiles.ini: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profiles.ini_file